# How to get the text color used for buttons on some Android dialogs themes programmatically?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm using [this helper method](https://github.com/amirzaidi/DeskClock/blob/e0a6cc08664ef462d3ffc89402dbcd50c79e3454/src/com/android/deskclock/ThemeUtils.java#L44) to get some colors for attributes, for instance using the style `ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` like so:

```
int colors [] = {
  R.attr.color,
  R.attr.colorAccent,
  R.attr.colorBackgroundFloating,
  R.attr.colorButtonNormal,
  R.attr.colorControlActivated,
  R.attr.colorControlHighlight,
  R.attr.colorControlNormal,
  R.attr.colorError,
  R.attr.colorPrimary,
  R.attr.colorPrimaryDark,
  R.attr.actionMenuTextColor,
  R.attr.editTextColor,
  R.attr.subtitleTextColor,
  R.attr.titleTextColor,
  R.attr.textColorAlertDialogListItem
};

for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  int color = ThemeUtils.resolveColor(new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT), colors[i]);
  Log.i("!!!!", String.format("%d %d", i, color));
}
```

The problem is that all attributes seem to return -65536

```
I/!!!!: 0 -65536
...
I/!!!!: 14 -65536
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:

int colors [] = {
                        R.attr.color,
                        R.attr.colorAccent,
                        R.attr.colorBackgroundFloating,
                        R.attr.colorButtonNormal,
                        R.attr.colorControlActivated,
                        R.attr.colorControlHighlight,
                        R.attr.colorControlNormal,
                        R.attr.colorError,
                        R.attr.colorPrimary,
                        R.attr.colorPrimaryDark,
                        R.attr.actionMenuTextColor,
                        R.attr.editTextColor,
                        R.attr.subtitleTextColor,
                        R.attr.titleTextColor,
                        R.attr.textColorAlertDialogListItem
                };
                Resources.Theme theme =  this.getTheme();
                TypedArray ta = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,colors);

                int[] color = new int[colors.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
                    color[i] = ta.getColor(i, 0);
                    Log.i("!!!!", String.format("%d %d", i, color[i]));
                }
```

Comment: All colors return zero, is that because the application theme is `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`? However the code is in a library, so I don't have control over what's used for the app theme.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your activity is either missing a theme or that your theme does not extend a default theme or one of the support library parent themes.

Your activity's theme should look something like this if you're using the support library:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Also check that your manifest file defines a theme for your activity or application:

```
    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:theme="@style/YourActivityTheme">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: The code is part of a library, so I don't have control over those files, is there a way to add the themes to the library?